# NHibernate protected internal vs internal

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'll need to preface this with the fact that I am a complete newbie when it comes to nhibernate, and I don't know what I don't know.

I have a user class like so:

```
public class nhMembershipUser : MembershipUser
{
    public new virtual Guid ProviderUserKey { get; set; }
    public new virtual DateTime LastPasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    protected internal virtual byte[] Password { get; set; }
    protected internal virtual string Salt { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Application { get; set; }
    public new virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public override bool IsOnline
    {
        get
        {
            var UnitOfWork = new nhUnitOfWork();
            return UnitOfWork.UserIsOnline(this);
        }
    }
    public new virtual bool IsLockedOut { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<nhRole> Roles { get; set; }

}
```

... and a fluent mapping class like so:

```
public class nhMembershipUserMap : ClassMap<nhMembershipUser>
{
    public nhMembershipUserMap()
    {
        Table("Users");
        Id(x => x.ProviderUserKey).Column("UserID");
        Map(x => x.Comment).Nullable().Length(10000);
        Map(x => x.CreationDate).CustomType<UtcDateTimeType>().Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Email).Not.Nullable().Length(250);
        Map(x => x.IsApproved).Default("1");
        Map(x => x.IsLockedOut).Default("0");
        Map(x => x.LastActivityDate).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.LastLockoutDate).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.LastLoginDate).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.LastPasswordChangedDate).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.PasswordQuestion).Nullable().Length(250);
        Map(x => x.ProviderName).Default("").Not.Nullable().Length(250);
        Map(x => x.UserName).Not.Nullable().Length(250);
        Map(x => x.IsEnabled).Default("1").Not.Nullable();
        Map(Reveal.Member<nhMembershipUser>("Password")).Length(260).Nullable();
        Map(Reveal.Member<nhMembershipUser>("Salt")).Length(250).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.FirstName).Length(35).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.LastName).Length(35).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Application).Length(250).Not.Nullable();
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Roles).ChildKeyColumn("RoleId").ParentKeyColumn("UserId").Cascade.All().Table("UsersToRoles");

    }
}
```

This builds, but of course I can't get or set the Salt or Password properties outside the class, which is bogus.  I'm trying to keep my user class light and POCO-ish and build the salting and hashing functionality into my membership provider; I really don't want the public having access but I want my provider class to.  The obvious answer is to use an internal access modifier but NH barks at me when I do that without a protected modifier and that defeats the purpose.

How can I have another class in my assembly access these restricted properties and save to NHibernate?  It seems like this should be easily doable.

Comment: In what assembly is you "membership provider"? The same as nhMembershipUser?

Comment: Yes.  Same assembly, but the protected modifier requirement of NH is seriously cramping my style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class nhMembershipUser : MembershipUser
{
    private byte[] PasswordHash;
    private string Salt;

    public void SetPassword(ICredentialsProvider provider)
    {
        PasswordHash = provider.GetHash(this);
        Salt = provider.GetSalt(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this be accessible to nhibernate?

Comment: Actually, this isn't a really good fit for what I'm trying to do.  First, it's definitely making my class considerably less POCO-ish, and second, it implies I have to put all the mechanisms in the user object... which sucks.

Comment: just how i would do it, if you dont like it fine. Nevertheless you mean less DTO-ish (only Data) because its still agnostic to persistance and the mechanics which calculate the hash. And your IsOnline also contradicts POCO

Comment: Field setter rather than public property setters is the way to but I got shot down for that the last time answered so I'll just comment ;)

Comment: @Firo sorry didn't meant to be critical... wasn't suggesting your code was bad, just the choices I have.  You're quite right about the IsOnline thing, but I'm trying to override its default behavior (from the `MembershipUser` class) so I don't have much choice there... it just seems like I'd have some options that don't seem to exist.

Comment: can you use DI for a service/unitOfWork which can tell if the user is online or not? then there even doesn't have to be a NHMembershipUser, just your own